# Sticky Sessions and Zuul in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a set of micro services and we use zuul for routing from the front end as a way of mapping a uri context path to a specific micro service using spring cloud.

Internally and externally we use spring OAuth2 and that works quite well.

However, for one specific service there has arisen a requirement for SAML and this imposes a sticky sessions requirement for that service.

Has another considered this and what would eb the correct way to put in sticky session support for zuul.

As a work around until I figure this out, I am routing some requests form the HAProxy that we have on the front end directly to this service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume if you need sticky sessions that you have multiple backends, so you must be using the Ribbon filter. Sticky sessions could be added as an `IRule`, e.g.

```
@RibbonClient(value="myui", configuration=UiRibbonConfiguration.class)
public class UiRibbonConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public IRule loadBalancerRule() {
    return new MyStickySessionRule();
  }
}
```

plus a `ZuulFilter` (or a servlet `Filter` in your backend) that adds a cookie for correlation - each backend instance has to uniquely identify itself, and then in the `MyStickySessionRule` you have to look at the incoming cookie to decide which instance to send the request to (e.g. you could send the "X-Application-Context" header value as a cookie if the backend is a Spring Boot app).

N.B. if you can use Spring Session in the backend you won't need sticky sessions.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at Spring Session now. Now to figure out how to get Spring SAML to work with it.  :)

Comment: Should be transparent.

Comment: Hi guys, have you solved the problem? Can you share the solution? (preferably with full code :)

Comment: Hi Tomasz, we ended up using Spring Session and that was a better solution for use.  Then I did not have to be concerned with implementing sticky sessions.  I did look at how i might do it with Rules and it did not look that difficult.

Comment: In case somebody is interested, I implemented an IRule for sticky sessions using @DaveSyer's suggestion: https://github.com/alejandro-du/vaadin-microservices-demo/blob/master/proxy-server/src/main/java/com/example/StickySessionRule.java